# Two elements in ConstaintLayout overlap each other

Tags: android, android-constraintlayout

I want to create a list item using ConstraintLayout. Just one line, one View on left and on on the right. But if the first one it too long it overlap another. How to avoid it? Is it possible to make left View be in two lines or make ... before the right one?

Code:

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.holodynskyi.v.test.MainActivity">

    <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_margin="8dp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/text1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            android:text="Text111111111111111111111111"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/text2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
            android:text="Text2"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent" />
    </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: why do you have an additional constraint layout nested in the root constraint layout ?

Comment: @Louis I created it just for test

Comment: @VolodymyrH you want to achieve this by only constraint layout?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use a [Guideline](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/constraint/Guideline.html)   to define an invisible limit between TextView1 and TextView2.

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/text1"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            android:text="Text1Text1Text1Text1Text1Text1Text1Text1Text1Text1Text1Text1Text1Text1Text1Text1Text1Text1Text1Text1Text1Text1Text1Text1"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@id/endOfText1"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/text2"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
            android:text="Text2"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/endOfText1" />

        <android.support.constraint.Guideline
            android:id="@+id/endOfText1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.75" />

    </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_weight="1"
        android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzhhjkjhjkhadlkhjajsdlkjalkdjlkajdlkjaldkjaljljadjaldjaljd"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/text2"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text2"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_weight="2"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzhhjkjhjkhadlkhjajsdlkjalkdjlkajdlkjaldkjaljljadjaldjaljd"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/text1"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />


</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

modify app:layout_constraintHorizontal_weight value to your requirement

Answer (score 0):

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.holodynskyi.v.test.MainActivity">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/text1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            android:text="any text"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/text2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="any text 2"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```